# How to add variable to data of scraped web tables

Tags: r, rvest

I want to scrape tables from several pages of UEFA site ([like this one](http://www.uefa.com/teamsandplayers/players/player=1900730/profile/index.html)) and try to merge it into one dataframe. The dataframe should have all information which is on single player's page (table "MATCH LOG") plus column (variable) with name of a player.

Solution by Chris works fine, but I'd like to grab name of player from the top of a page (selector'.bigTitle') not from the box "GENERAL INFO".

My code that makes the dataframe:

```
length_links <- length(links)
all_tables <- vector("list",length_links)
for(i in seq_len(length_links)){
  page <- html(links[i])
  all_tables[[i]] <- as.data.frame(html_table(page))
}

do.call(rbind, all_tables)
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code for what `links` might look like, and also a more detailed description of your desired output?

Comment: 'links' is a vector with several urls (eg. Diego Costa's [link](http://www.uefa.com/teamsandplayers/players/player=1900730/profile/index.html) and other spanish players web pages on UEFA site). I'd like to combine "Match log" tables of all players into one and add a name of a player to the dataframe

[link]:

Comment: Welcome you SO! A more reproducible escape would let us show you how to use lapply to optimize the whole operation

Comment: While trying to run your code on a `links` variable containing Diego Costa's [link](http://www.uefa.com/teamsandplayers/players/player=1900730/profile/index.html) your line `all_tables[[i]] <- as.data.frame(html_table(page))` returns an error - is this consistent with what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

c('http://www.uefa.com/teamsandplayers/players/player=1900730/profile/index.html',
  'http://www.uefa.com/teamsandplayers/players/player=250078460/profile/index.html',
  'http://www.uefa.com/teamsandplayers/players/player=250045034/profile/index.html') -> links

namefind <- function(text){
    str_extract(string = text, pattern = "Name.+Position") -> xx
    substr(xx, start = 6, stop = nchar(xx)) -> u
    u
}

length_links <- length(links)
all_tables <- vector("list",length_links)
for(i in seq_len(length_links)){
    html(links[i])  -> q
    html_table(q, fill = TRUE)-> tableList
    if(length(tableList) == 0) next
    for(cc in 1:length(tableList)){
        if(all(colnames(tableList[[cc]])[1:3] == c("Date", "Competition", "Phase"))) {
            all_tables[[i]] <- tableList[[cc]]
            all_tables[[i]]$name <- html_text(html_node(q, css = '.bigTitle'))
        }
    }
}

do.call(rbind, all_tables) -> k
k[k$Date != "The home team is listed first.",] -> k
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. What if wanted to extract a name from the top of a page (selector '.bigTitle')?

Comment: I edited the response to pull the name from the top.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's perfect